# symfony post api is taking too much time to load

Tags: php, performance, file, symfony

I have a api, which will upload the images of the users to server.

It will take the images in base64 format and send that to server. But the problem is for some user it will take long time, and for some user it works well.

I am not getting why this is happening. But the destination directory is a having 700GB of data.

code for uploading : 
`
$file will be having base64 format of image
$this->file = $file;

```
    if ($this->id && !empty($this->path) && !is_null($file)) {
        $this->storeFilenameForRemove();
    }

    if ($file instanceof File) {

        if (isset($this->path)) {
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    } else if (gettype($file) == 'string') {

        if (preg_match('/data:(\w+)\/(\w+);base64,/i', $file, $matches)) {

            if ($matches) {

                $file = preg_replace('/data:(\w+)\/(\w+);base64,/i', '', $file);

                $tmpFile = Array();
                $tmpFile['data'] = base64_decode( str_replace(' ', '+', $file) );

                if ($matches[1] === 'image') {

                    $tmpFile['name'] = uniqid().'.png';
                } else {

                    $tmpFile['name'] = uniqid().'.'.$matches[2];
                }

                $tmpFile['handle'] = fopen( $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$tmpFile['name'], 'w' );

                // inject the raw image data into the new file
                fwrite( $tmpFile['handle'], $tmpFile['data'] );
                fclose( $tmpFile['handle'] );

                $this->path = $tmpFile['name'];
            }
        }
    } else {

        $this->file = $file;
    }`
```

Comment: i was thinking it's about the size of the file , but you just tell us that it's work ( means upload is quick ) for some users  . so it's maybe for your logic statements , how you interpret you upload , what conditions you use , please share some code here so we can help you

Comment: File size and the internet line speed capability would affect each user differently.

Comment: file size is not much and internet speed is 90Mbps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if executing a preg_match on a base64 encoded string is a good idea, while I'm not sure that fixes all of your problems regarding speed I'm positive that implementing a different check for base64 encoded strings would improve the speed.

Replace the following:

```
if (preg_match('/data:(\w+)\/(\w+);base64,/i', $file, $matches)) {
```

with this

```
if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($file)) === $file){
```